# AngularJS attribute comment in raw HTML

Tags: angularjs, eclipse

Why are the comments of my AngularJS attributes in raw HTML and how do I fix it?

※ Eclipse (Kepler Service Release 2)

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question. Your issue is about AngularJS validation in HTML files (Eclipse)?

Comment: @Mistalis Hovering the mouse over an Angular attribute should give a rendered comment. For some reason, it is in raw HTML on my installation. The validation is done just fine, the comment, however is displayed strangely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **AngularJS Eclipse Plugin** is not supported in Eclipse Kepler.

> AngularJS Eclipse is developed/tested with Eclipse 4.4 Luna. It is advised to use Eclipse 4.4 Luna (even if AngularJS Eclipse could work with older version of Eclipse).

Source: [angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse](https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse)